# Rails 5 - Acts as Taggable On - unpermitted params for specific tag list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on, white-labelling

I am trying to get acts as taggable on setup to work with my Rails 5 app.

I have a model called Randd::Field.rb, which has an attribute called :title in it. I want to use those titles as tags for my proposal model.

My Proposal.rb has:

class Proposal < ApplicationRecord
  include Statesman::Adapters::ActiveRecordQueries

```
  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_taggable_on :randd_maturities, :randd_fields, :randd_purposes, :randd_activities
```

My proposal form.html.erb has:

```
<%= f.collection_select :randd_field_list, Randd::Field.order(:title), :id, :title, {}, {multiple: true} %>
```

My proposal controller whitelists the randd_field_list with:

```
  def proposal_params
      params.require(:proposal).permit(:title, :randd_maturities_list, :randd_field_list, :randd_purposes_list, :randd_activities_list)
```

When I save all of this and try to add a tag to a proposal, I get an error.  The server log shows:

```
Unpermitted parameter: randd_field_list
```

This doesn't make any sense because its a problem that comes up when the attribute is not whitelisted in the permitted params - which I have done.

Can anyone see what needs to be done in order to save tags via the proposal form?

I find the gem documentation confusing because it shows:

> Setup
>
> class User < ActiveRecord::Base   acts_as_taggable # Alias for
>   acts_as_taggable_on :tags   acts_as_taggable_on :skills, :interests
>   end
>
> class UsersController < ApplicationController   def user_params
>       params.require(:user).permit(:name, :tag_list) ## Rails 4 strong params usage   end end

Why doesn't the permitted params include a :skill_list and an :interest_list given that those specific models are used as tags?  Am I supposed to add "tag_list" to my proposal permitted params even when the only tags that can be added are from the titles defined in the specific models I've listed in:

```
acts_as_taggable_on :randd_maturities, :randd_fields, :randd_purposes, :randd_activities
```

The server log shows:

```
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "taggings".* FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2  [["taggable_id", 17], ["taggable_type", "Proposal"]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND (taggings.context = 'randd_fields' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)  [["taggable_id", 17], ["taggable_type", "Proposal"]]



  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Load (2.8ms)  SELECT "taggings".* FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2  [["taggable_id", 17], ["taggable_type", "Proposal"]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND (taggings.context = 'randd_fields' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)  [["taggable_id", 17], ["taggable_type", "Proposal"]]
  Randd::Field Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "randd_fields".* FROM "randd_fields" ORDER BY "randd_fields"."title" ASC


Processing by ProposalsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BF7l9/0QTVN3A==", "proposal"=>{"title"=>"asdf", "byline"=>"asdf", , "randd_field_list"=>["", "1"], 

Unpermitted parameter: randd_field_list
```

Comment: show your log for this request, especially incoming parameters. In documentation is used :tag_list because :tags is default for `acts_as_taggable_on`. They too should add :skill_list into that example.

Comment: @AlexKojin - I added the server log extracts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send an array for *_list parameters. Try to add [] for every _list in permit method:

```
params.require(:proposal).permit(
  :title, 
  randd_maturities_list: [], 
  randd_field_list: [], 
  randd_purposes_list: [], 
  randd_activities_list: [])
```

Comment: That stops the unpermitted param error, but the tag doest save to the proposal. Do I need to do something in the proposal controller to actually add the form selection to the proposal array for the randd_field_list?

Comment: I think, no. You need to check your log.